# How to pass template from parent to child using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have create a simple table wrapper component in Angular. In wrapper component in 1st column I wanted to show custom template.

My main challange is here to write all the template of that column in parent component only.

Means Whatever template I am giving in parent, at that particular row that template should be shown.

I tried something like this

[Stackblit Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15kpk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything correctly in your code sample, all you need is to add a `ng-template` to your html file and it will work fine.

With your row code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of options">
      <td>
        <ng-container
          *ngTemplateOutlet="columnTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }"
        ></ng-container>
      </td>
      <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Adding this will display the item name:

```
<ng-template #columnTemplate let-item>
  {{ item.name }}
</ng-template>
```

Working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15kpk2-jwsvw9)

If you need anything more complex, I would advise you build a service to share data between this and the parent component.